# How can I copy a file from one directory to all locations returned by "find" command in Linux?

Tags: linux, cp

I executed "find" command as :

```
[root@XXXXX ~]# find / -name "dba-3.2.0.0.jar"
/abc/XXXXitrpwf/workflow/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrprpt/reporting/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrpmhost/technology/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrpressvc/service/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrpac/technology/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrpui/services/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrpdm/technology/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrpsm/technology/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
/abc/XXXXitrplic/licensing/lib/dba-3.2.0.0.jar
```

Now I want to overwrite `dba-3.2.0.0.jar` by `/tmp/dba-3.2.0.0.jar` at all the locations.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
find / -name "dba-3.2.0.0.jar" -exec cp /tmp/dba-3.2.0.0.jar {} \;
```

Where `{}` will be replaced by each file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs`

```
find / -name "dba-3.2.0.0.jar" | xargs -I{} cp {} /destination/path
```

Command tested on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score -1):

```
find / -name "nametofind" -exec cp {} /output/directory/goes/here \;
```

Comment: This would copy the many things found all into a single output directory, which is the inverse of what the OP wants; copy one source file into many matching destination directories.